# java infix expression derivation

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I have 2 strings

```
String expression = add(,subtract(,));

String values = (3,(10,4));
```

I want to evaluate the expression.. So the output should be like below.

```
add(3 , subtract(10,4) )
```

**What I tried:**  The approach i tried is remove special chars from expression , tokenize and store the function names in an array.. So in above example the array will be having add , subtract.  Then , loop and replace 3 with add(3) and  10,4 with subtract(10,4).  I am getting desired output if I have only 1 or 2 functions.  But if there are multiple nested functions , I am unable to derive the output for expressions like below.

For ex:

```
 expression= add(subtract(,) , multiply(,)) 
 value = ( (4,3)  , (2,2) )  

output = add( subtract(4,3) , multiply(2,2))
```

Comment: dint get you.. I am using 2 diferent arraylist or arrays. convert string to char array and check for open bracket and close bracket..

Comment: agreed.. but i am not able to get logic for the mentioned complex expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below procedure to achieve your result:

**Proposed procedure:**

```
//base case
1. if count of'(' != count of ')' // unbalanced parenthesis
    print 'Invalid Expression'
    exit the program
2. Store all the operations (like add, subtract, multiply,etc.) from the expressions string.
3. for char ch in values
     replace each occurrence of open parenthesis(() with  stored operation in step 2 along with (.
```

**Implementation of the above procedure in java(I recommend you please try your own ways to implement the above procedure. The code can be optimized further):**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main{
// Regex to extract all the operations from the expression string.
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String expression = "add(divide(add(,),) , subtract(,))";
        String value = "(((5 , 5), 2),(10,4))";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // To store the final result.
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>(); //to store all the operations from the expression string.
        if(count(value, '(') != count(value,')')){
            System.out.println("Invalid expression");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(matcher.find())
            arr.add(matcher.group(0));
        int counter = 0;
        for(char ch: value.toCharArray()){
            if(ch == '('){
               sb.append(arr.get(counter) + "(");
               // counter only gets incremented if operations get appended to sb
               counter++;
            }
            else sb.append(ch);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
// utility method to fulfill step 1 of proposed procedure.
    public static int count(String str, char ch){
        int count = 0;
        for(char chr:str.toCharArray()){
            if(chr == ch)count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/r1WmNaVn8)

Comment: Thanks Mandy... will try ur solution and let u know in a while

Comment: your solution worked absolutely fine.. Thank you for ur prompt help